# Reverting Form Data with Cancel button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Is there an elegant way to insert a cancel (or revert) button next to a form that would essentially revert the contents of the form before the user starting making edits.

For example,

1. A user has an account and wants to change their user name.
2. They come to the form, see that the input field has the username populated: joeuser
3. They start editing the field and change their mind
4. The click cancel/revert and the field reverts back to username: joeuser --the form doesn't just reset with empty fields

Possible with resorting to too much hackery?  I thought maybe HTML5 history API could be used to for this in some way.

Comment: can you take the form, clone it, keep the clone in memory, and if the user hits cancel, replace the form with the cloned copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use jQuery: 
    $("#formID")[0].reset();

Comment: Do you see the tag `jquery`?

Comment: nope. so what? it's the same thing as document.forms[0].reset() (just change the index in case there are multiple forms)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery:

```
$('#FormID').each(function(){
  this.reset();
});
```

else you can use this:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
```

Comment: Do you see the tag `jquery`?

Comment: @LightStyle OP did not specify...and I am adding in a pure JS solution as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this one, passing the form element as variable:

```
function resetForm(form) {
    var elems = form.elements;
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var current = elems[i],
            type = current.type.toLowerCase();
        switch (type) {
            case "select-one":
            case "select-multi":
                current.selectedIndex = -1;
                break;
            case "checkbox":
            case "radio":
                if (current.checked) {
                    current.checked = false;
                }
                break;
            case "password":
            case "textarea":
            case "text":
            case "hidden":
                current.value = "";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is just to clear the form, you can use cookies to save the username and restore it via this simple function.

Comment: you can clear a form with `<input type="reset" value="Reset" />`

Comment: That's not exactly the same thing, that one reset the form to the default values, mine reset form to "blank" values